# Convert ipynb to pdf in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am new to ipython notebook, and I would like to convert my ipynb to pdf. But I get the following error when I try to Download as PDF via LaTex.

```
nbconvert failed: pdflatex not found on PATH
```

There is no documentation anywhere how to add pdflatex to my PATH. I use windows. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have Latex installed? If not, you need to install it, in the form of something like [MikTex](http://miktex.org/). If you do have it, there are instructions on changing the path [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: @ThomasK Thank you! You mean to add the path of where miktex was installed?

Comment: It should install somewhere a `pdflatex.exe` file. PATH needs to include the directory that contains that.

Comment: I get `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`

Comment: when I go to download Latex it says download MikTex so, my .exe says basic-miktex-2.9.6850-x64 - I have this in the same path as where my ipynb file is but it still does not work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As said by [Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k) in the comments, you need to have Latex installed, and after add the path to the directory containing `pdflatex.exe` file to the `PATH` variable of your system.

I have looked for a lightweight distribution and tried installing [TeXworks](https://www.tug.org/texworks/), but I didn't find any `pdflatex.exe` file.
So I have tried [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), which worked fine creating the `pdflatex.exe` file under the target installation directory. This path should be like `C:\...\texlive\2016\bin\win32`.
Finally, you should just add this path to the `PATH` environment variable of your system (you can use the link shared by [Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k)).

As said [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/799#issuecomment-539905612), you need to quit jupyter notebook and open a new command prompt after making any path changes, in order for jupyter to find the newly added item to the `PATH`.

Then, in Jupyter, you can check your environment variables by running the following (refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/access-environment-variables-from-python#4907053) for details):

```
    import os
    os.environ['PATH'].split(';')
```

and check if it contains the path to `pdflatex.exe` file.

If you get some trouble when exporting your notebook to pdf due to missing files/packages (this happened to me), refer to this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274536/find-the-right-package-for-missing-files-in-texlive) to search and install them under TeX Live.

Comment: this solution is for Windows - see below for Mac OS X version

Comment: One minor point... you need to restart jupyter notebook in a new command prompt in order to see the newly added PATH items

Answer (score 47):

A simple and surprisingly good solution is to print the notebook to pdf through the browser with `ctrl+p`. Just make sure your plots and figures are not on interactive mode otherwise they will not be displayed (set them to `%matplotlib inline`).

Exporting jupyter notebooks through latex is quite troublesome and takes a lot of tinkering to get something remotely close to publish ready. When I absolutely need publication quality I do it on a latex editor, but this [tutorial](http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook) goes in great length about doing it on jupyter.

A few useful tips to get better results:

- [Higher resolution plots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161614/4438281)
- [Hide your code-cells from the pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer)
- Take a look at [these extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) to improve your jupyter documents

Comment: ctrl+p is the best thing I read on stack overflow ever. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

For Mac OS X, the solution for me was to install [MacTex](http://tug.org/mactex/) first and then export the path to find it:

```
### TeX
export PATH="/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin:$PATH"
```

You can add this to your `.bash_profile` or similar config file to load it every time.

See more here https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/406

Comment: Worked perfectly on MacOS in my `zshrc`. Thanks

Comment: how on earth this Mactex thing can take 3.9Gb to download?

Comment: For newer versions of MacTeX: `export PATH="/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 12):

For Linux, the reported error is due to the lack of `XeLatex`, part of the `texlive-xetex` package.

Installation in ubuntu will be:
`sudo apt install texlive-xetex`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using nbconvert what you can do is :

1. Download your ipynb file as HTML from File option.
2. Right-click and select print or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Save as PDF

Easy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full solution that worked for me (for Mac).

`brew cask install mactex`

`$ cd ~/`

`$ touch .bash_profile`

This will open the bash profile on TextEditor

`$ open -e .bash_profile`

Paste the following to the top and save

```
export PATH="/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin:$PATH"
```

Close any notebook you have and reopen it

Here is the notebook explaining it step by step:
https://github.com/ybaktir/notes/blob/master/Convert%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20to%20Pdf.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

I agree that latex installation (at least on windows) is painful and the result in my case was not a great looking document. The `ctrl-p` method alone doesn't work great if you're running in JupyterLab, but if you export the notebook to HTML, then print from the browser, choosing PDF, the result is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

I know my solution is not at a level. But it works !!

in your browser of notebook tab, simply do "ctrl + p" to get download in pdf

Answer (score 1):

First export the notebook file to HTML (available through File> Download as..).
If you are using JupyterLab, then this is available under **File** > **Export Notebook As...**.
Use (any) free online converters to convert html file to a pdf file. (One such free online converter is `sejda` (https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf)

Note, there are many such converters are available online.