# Jupyter notebook could not convert to pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, ipython, nbconvert

I was trying to convert my notebook to .pdf file but instead I got this "500:Internal Server Error - nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex."

I checked my jupyter and I have installed nbconvert 5.6.1.  Ay help is greatly appreciated.

I followed the suggested installation and still no luck

I tried to upload the file to Jupyter lab to convert it online. And even that got the same error message.

Thanks!

Comment: `xelatex not found on PATH` do you install this?

Comment: Yes, I did textlive2020 the mac equivalence of xelatex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving "500: Internal Server Error, nbconvert failed: xelatex not found in PATH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300242/solving-500-internal-server-error-nbconvert-failed-xelatex-not-found-in-path)